# How to create the below widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-ios, flutter-android

[image: Progress bar image]

Can anyone please help to draw this widget in flutter.
This image have 2 Text at top and at bottom it's kind of progress bar.

Comment: Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Answer (score 0):

You can try [fl_chart plugin on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart)

or check out this search in the pub.dev:

https://pub.dev/packages?q=charts